# Is there a function $f(x)$ such that $f(-x) = f(x) + \pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

We have:
$$e^{-it} = \cos(t) - i \sin(t)$$
$$\cos(t+\pi) = -\cos(t)$$
$$\sin(t+\pi) = -\sin(t)$$

Therefore:
$$e^{-it} = -e^{-i(t+\pi)}$$

With a variable $x$, and a function $f(x)$:
$$xe^{-if(x)} = (-x)e^{-i(f(x)+\pi)}$$

What $f(x)$ satisfies the above equality?
It can be rewritten as:
$$f(-x) = f(x) + \pi$$

Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As $2=-(-2)$, the equality you want gives $f(2)=f(-(-2))=f(-2)+\pi=f(2)+2\pi$, that is absurd. So you can obviously only have that equation satisfied on $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: For $x=0$ you would get $f(0)=f(0)+\pi$, a contradiction.

Comment: If you have $e^{-it}=-e^{-i(t+\pi)}$
 and $t=f(x)$
 then $e^{-if(x)}=-e^{-i(f(x)+\pi)}$
 and you could multiply both sides by $x$
 to give  $x\,e^{-if(x)}=-x\,e^{-i(f(x)+\pi)}$. This does not lead to  $f(-x)=f(x)+\pi$ .  Nor does  $e^{-it}=e^{-i(t+2\pi)}$ lead to $t=t+2\pi$ , since complex logarithms are not single valued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(-x)=f(x)+\pi$ for all $x$.  Then
$$
f(x) + f(-x)=f(-x)+\pi+f(x)+\pi
$$
so $0=2\pi$.  There is no such function.

Comment: Even for $x > 0$ ?

Comment: The equation $f(-x) = f(x)+\pi$ involves both $x$ and $-x$.  So of course $f$ must be defined for both nonpositive and nonnegative $x$.

Comment: Yes ok it makes sense. Sorry it looks like a dumb question now